# Form: make fields in the same row have the same length

Tags: sapui5

[image: Screenshot of sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm with two dropdown controls in the same row]

In this `sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm`, I have 2 controls in the same row. Right now, they're somewhat uneven without any formatting done to them. How do I make these 2 controls both occupy 50% of the total row space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be seen in the following sample:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.SimpleFormToolbar

Basically all controls have the aggregation `<layoutData>`. There you can add your own layout information:

```xml
<Input value="{ZIPCode}">
    <layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="XL2 L1 M3 S4" />
    </layoutData>
</Input>
```

Of course this also works for a `Select`.

Now you just have to determine what you want to pass to the `span` property:

Usually layouts are based on a 12 column grid. You have to assign some columns to your `Labels`, maybe some empty space at the end and the rest belongs to your `Inputs` or `Selects`.

Your `SimpleForm` will probably have these properties:

```xml
<f:SimpleForm layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
    labelSpanXL="4"
    labelSpanL="4"
    labelSpanM="4"
    labelSpanS="12"
    emptySpanXL="0"
    emptySpanL="4"
    emptySpanM="0"
    emptySpanS="0">
```

So for XL you see that 4 columns already belong to the `Label` and 0 to empty space at the end so you have 8 columns left. Therefore both form controls should get 4 columns.
L has 4 `Label` columns and 4 empty columns so each form control should get 2 columns.
M is similar to XL.
S already has 12 columns for the `Label`. Therefore your controls will be pushed into a second row below the `Label` where they each can use 6 columns.

So in that example I would suggest passing the following `layoutData` to both controls so they take equal space. If your `SimpleForm` has different values for label space end empty space then you have to recalculate.

```xml
<l:GridData span="XL4 L2 M4 S6" />
```

Remember to declare the `l` namespace at the beginning of your `View` so you can use the `GridData` control:

```xml
<mvc:View
    ...
    ...
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">
```